# file /dev/adm taking too much space disk

Tags: debian

I'm the admin of a VPS, and I saw that 65GB over my 100GB are taken by a file in /dev/adm

I used "df -h" to see my disk space left, and make "du -h" in / folder.
I found that this file "/dev/adm" is taking all the space. What is this file? Can I safely remove it? or Purge it?

I'm on Debian 7.

Thank you for your answers.

**EDIT** : /dev/adm is not a folder, it's a file.

Comment: I don't even have a /dev/adm on my Debian Wheezy system (but that, by itself, doesn't mean it can't be legitimate). However, any large file (or indeed any regular file at all) in /dev on a modern system would set off massive alarms in my mind, to the tune of "you have been pwned".

Comment: Is it a file, or char/block device? `ls -al /dev/adm` What kind of data is inside? `file -s /dev/adm` Is it growing?